# positioning/spacing/centering table data

Tags: css, html

I'm having issues properly centering this. I believe the whole table is offset to the left a little, but what I really notice are the icons.  They should be to the right just a hair. I could add margin to slide it over a bit more, but I'm looking for something precise.  It bothers me not knowing exactly how many pixels I'm off by.  Would someone be able to tell me what my issues are here?  And for the record I'm ridiculously new to coding and wasn't quite sure what my direction was going to be when I started this.  I'm sure there are redundancies/inefficiencies in the css code.   Here's a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/smatchymo/rdxh9hd4/8/

And here's the code.

```
<body>
  <div id='filter'></div>
  <div id='watchface'></div>
  <div id='text'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class='times'>4:00</td>
        <td id='icon' class='icons'></td>
        <td class='hourTemp'>69</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='times'>5:00</td>
        <td id='icon1' class='icons'></td>
        <td class='hourTemp'>67</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='timecapsule'>
    <div id='permatime'></div>
    <div id='time'>12:00</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#watchface {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  //background-color: black;
  z-index: 0;
}

#timecapsule {
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#permatime {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  left: 105px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  //border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .7;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 40;
}

#time {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 105px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 41;
}


#filter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
  z-index: 2;
}

#text {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
  //overflow: auto;
}

.icons {
  height: 37px;
  width: 112px;
  // border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#icon {
  background: url("https://icons.wxug.com/i/c/v4/chancetstorms.svg") no-repeat center;
}

#icon1 {
  background: url("https://icons.wxug.com/i/c/v4/flurries.svg") no-repeat center;
}

.hourTemp {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 74px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.times {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  //border: 1px solid lime;
  width: 74px;
}

table {
  padding: 75px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin; 0px;
  width: 360px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 32px;
}

td {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bahhh, I swear I double checked my math...  I was just about to make an edit to my post adding up the pixel sizes of the table data and padding to make things easier and clearer for anyone trying to help, but I realized everything doesn't add to 360 pixels as it should.  My icon class width is 10px too small...